# Image src using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, src

I have the image path as shown below:

```
<img src='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='70' height='55'/>
```

And Now I want to click this thumbnail image in order to display its orginal image.
For that I am doing like this:

```
 $(".imgContain").click(function () {
                $('#<%=largeImage.ClientId%>').attr('src','Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "');

  });
```

When I do this way and checked its src it's showing me as "Failed to load give URL".
Can anyone edit me this src or point me out which is the best way to do this?

This is my HTML part:

```
<div id="thumbs" class="imgContain" runat="server">
    </div>

<asp:Image ID="largeImage" runat="server" 
        style="position:relative;width:450px;height:345px; margin-left:430px;margin-top:-415px; margin-bottom:30px;" 
        BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="4px"/>
```

Comment: is your javascript in an external file by any chance?

Comment: @Mikey-No it was within the main script

Comment: Can you show us the actual generated HTML rather than your ASP code.  We don't know what actually gets put in the page so we don't know what code is actually running (you probably don't know either).  The place to get the actual generated code is View/Source in the browser.

Comment: @jfriend-I have added the HTML part.

Comment: It looks like that string is a mess, check it out.

Comment: @gdoron-But it shows me the image for the above mentioned Image for the same path.

Comment: You can see an image browser like I think you're trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vfZmY/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah that string a little off.  Try it like this:

```
$('.imgContain').click(function () {
    $('#<%=largeImage.ClientId%>').attr('src','Uploads/' + $get('<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>').value + '/' + file.name);
});
```

it was kind of confusing because single and double quotations were being used interchangeably.

Comment: @Will-Thank you so much for the edit and for this really I pulled out my hair for the last 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but i think you might have to get the server tags out of the string.

Maybe something like this:

```
 $(".imgContain").click(function () {
                $('#' + <%=largeImage.ClientId%>).attr('src','Uploads"' + document.getElementById(<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>).value + "/" + file.name + "'");

  });
```